# what is the difference between seed and derandomize in python hypothesis testing framework?

Tags: python, python-hypothesis

In stateful test, If I use a fixed seed and setting.derandomize(True or False) together, what is the behavior of the randomize?

what confuse me is the following scenarios:

when I use a fixed seed and settings.derandomize=False, I will get different result when I rerun the test.

but when I use a fixed seed and settings.derandomize=True, I can get the same result when I rerun the test.

I want to find out why I get different result on different runs in the first scenario。 but I don't know how to do.

Comment: a quick glance of the code suggests that `settings.derandomize=False` potentially includes a hash of the test function as part of entropy, particularly if `global_force_seed is not None` but that is with a 20 second look at the code. You might be able to see more at `https://github.com/search?q=repo%3AHypothesisWorks%2Fhypothesis%20derandomize&type=code`

Answer (score 0):

`derandomize=True` has two effects:

1. Set a fixed seed based on a hash of the test function
2. Disable the database, so we don't replay previously-found examples

The idea is that the `@seed(...)` decorator is meant to help you reproduce a failure which was e.g. found in CI, and so replaying old examples is probably helpful or at worst adds a bit of latency; whereas if you pass `derandomize=True` you actually want determinism.

You can [read more about this in our docs](https://hypothesis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reproducing.html).  Fixed seeds can be convenient due to the command-line support via our Pytest plugin, but I'd generally avoid them otherwise in favor of the database and `@reproduce_failure()`.